# How are linked userid and hostid in Zabbix database?

Tags: zabbix

I want to create SQL script for DB Zabbix (3.4, MySQL version)
where will filter by userid and date 
and get information about hosts (for example created/changed hosts, add/changed media send information).

How are linked userid and hostid?

p.s.

mediatypeid

```
select * from zabbix.media med
join zabbix.users us ON us.userid=med.userid
join zabbix.media_type med_t on med_t.mediatypeid=med.mediatypeid
where
1=1
and med_t.mediatypeid=4
```

auditlog

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(log.clock),
log.* from zabbix.auditlog log
join zabbix.users us on us.userid=log.userid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User IDs and host IDs are not directly connected. The best you can hope for is using the information in the `auditlog` and `auditlog_details` tables, but keep in mind that many operations are not properly registered in the auditlog, especially in older versions.